# Sorting multidimensional array by two arrays PHP

Tags: php, html

So I got stuck with my friends `PHP` script. What I want to do is sort `pavadinimas` and If there is more than one the same `pavadinimas` then sort by `o_pavadinimas` , this part is ok. But then all the information goes randomly. I mean I sort only columns, but not rows.  Do you have any ideas guys, cause i ran out of it...

```
<?php

$file = "Muniko dešros&nbsp;Abraitis&nbsp;Vilius.munikas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.abraitis.lt&nbsp;Vilius&nbsp;Munikas&nbsp;Muniko dešros&nbsp;Belenkas&nbsp;Vilius.munikas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.belenkas.lt&nbsp;Vilius&nbsp;Munikas&nbsp;Tomo dešros&nbsp;Abraitis&nbsp;tomas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.abraitis.lt&nbsp;Tomas&nbsp;Vilemaitis&nbsp;Tomo dešros&nbsp;Belenkas&nbsp;tomas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.belenkas.lt&nbsp;Tomas&nbsp;Vilemaitis&nbsp;Dino dešros&nbsp;Dešrynas&nbsp;dinas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.derynas.lt&nbsp;Dinas&nbsp;Šukuosena&nbsp;Dino dešros&nbsp;Abraitis&nbsp;dinas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.abraitis.lt&nbsp;Dinas&nbsp;Šukuosena&nbsp;";

$masyvas = explode("&nbsp;", $file);
$x = count($masyvas);
print_r($masyvas);

$rikiavimas = array (
  'pavadinimas' => '',
  'o_pavadinimas' => '',
  'email' => '',
  'svetaines_adresas' => '',
  'vardas' => '',
  'pavarde' => ''
);       
$c=0;
while($c < $x-4){
$rikiavimas['pavadinimas'][] = $masyvas[$c+0];
$rikiavimas['o_pavadinimas'][] = $masyvas[$c+1];
$rikiavimas['email'][] = $masyvas[$c+2];
$rikiavimas['svetaines_adresas'][] = $masyvas[$c+3];
$rikiavimas['vardas'][] = $masyvas[$c+4];
$rikiavimas['pavarde'][] = $masyvas[$c+5];
$c+=6;
}
array_multisort($rikiavimas['pavadinimas'], SORT_ASC, SORT_REGULAR, $rikiavimas['o_pavadinimas']);

$pirmas=count($rikiavimas['pavadinimas']);
print_r($rikiavimas);
?>


<table class="table" align="center" width="800" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Produkto pavadinimas</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Organizacijos pavadinimas</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>El. paštas</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Svetainės adresas</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Vardas</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Pavardė</strong></td>
</tr>
 <?php
$y=0;
while($y < $pirmas){
echo "<td>" . $rikiavimas['pavadinimas'][$y] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $rikiavimas['o_pavadinimas'][$y] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $rikiavimas['email'][$y] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $rikiavimas['svetaines_adresas'][$y] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $rikiavimas['vardas'][$y] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $rikiavimas['pavarde'][$y] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$y++;
}
?>
 <?php

?>
</table>
```

EDIT: Ignore the `print_r` it's just for testing

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "The information goes randomly". I just copy pasted your code into a php file and it showed a fully populated and sorted table just as you require.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of what I see. http://postimg.org/image/3pep730wh/

Comment: @RubenFunai tho first column are sorted, but others just stays as they are. So when you sort two columns and not whole table the information goes randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related with a wrong usage of array_multisort. Currently, you're only sorting arrays **$rikiavimas['pavadinimas']** and **$rikiavimas['o_pavadinimas']**.

Arrays:

- $rikiavimas['email']
- $rikiavimas['svetaines_adresas']
- $rikiavimas['vardas']
- $rikiavimas['pavarde']

are left unmodified. array_multisort doesn't know anything about these 4 arrays.

I've modified a little bit your code => I've switched $rikiavimas[name][index] to $rikiavimas[index][name].

```
<?php

$file = "Muniko dešros&nbsp;Abraitis&nbsp;Vilius.munikas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.abraitis.lt&nbsp;Vilius&nbsp;Munikas&nbsp;Muniko dešros&nbsp;Belenkas&nbsp;Vilius.munikas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.belenkas.lt&nbsp;Vilius&nbsp;Munikas&nbsp;Tomo dešros&nbsp;Abraitis&nbsp;tomas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.abraitis.lt&nbsp;Tomas&nbsp;Vilemaitis&nbsp;Tomo dešros&nbsp;Belenkas&nbsp;tomas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.belenkas.lt&nbsp;Tomas&nbsp;Vilemaitis&nbsp;Dino dešros&nbsp;Dešrynas&nbsp;dinas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.derynas.lt&nbsp;Dinas&nbsp;Šukuosena&nbsp;Dino dešros&nbsp;Abraitis&nbsp;dinas@gmail.com&nbsp;Www.abraitis.lt&nbsp;Dinas&nbsp;Šukuosena&nbsp;";
$masyvas = explode("&nbsp;", $file);

$columns = 6;
$rikiavimas = array();
$masyvas = array_chunk($masyvas, $columns);

foreach ($masyvas as $value) {
  if (count($value) < $columns) continue;
  list($tmp['pavadinimas'],
       $tmp['o_pavadinimas'],
       $tmp['email'],
       $tmp['svetaines_adresas'],
       $tmp['vardas'],
       $tmp['pavarde']
   ) = $value;
   $rikiavimas[] = $tmp;
 }

 $sort = array();
 foreach($rikiavimas as $v) {
     $sort['pavadinimas'][] = $v['pavadinimas'];
     $sort['o_pavadinimas'][] = $v['o_pavadinimas'];
 }

 array_multisort($sort['pavadinimas'], SORT_ASC, SORT_REGULAR, $sort['o_pavadinimas'], SORT_ASC, SORT_REGULAR, $rikiavimas);
?>

<table class="table" align="center" width="800" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Produkto pavadinimas</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Organizacijos pavadinimas</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>El. paštas</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Svetainės adresas</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Vardas</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Pavardė</strong></td>
</tr>
 <?php
foreach ($rikiavimas as $row) {
 echo "<td>" . $row['pavadinimas'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['o_pavadinimas'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['svetaines_adresas'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['vardas'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['pavarde'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank your for your explanation, and it works very well!